# Chemical Structure of PLA soaked in Ethyl acetate

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I am trying to find a way to separate my PLA samples and ABS samples. Both of these are 3D printing plastics (*Polylactic acid* and *Acrylonitrile butadiene styrene*)

Last night I've observed:

- When soaked in Ethyl Acetate:

  - ABS disintegrates in about an hour,
  - PLA loses "fancy" properties, ( such as green/yellow color-changing filament, went blue. )
  - All PLA, fancy or standard, turns very flexible.

I would say this could be a good start for my process, as the ABS is separated from the PLA, but the PLA has changed now to a fairly unusable form, (the ABS especially so)

How can I understand this "flexible PLA" and the solution? I can see that the PLA has been chemically altered, but how? and can it be corrected? What happened to the Ethyl Acetate and the ABS?

I'm still quite noobish in chemistry, so I'm happy for anyone to throw a book at me or where I should start to learn about this.

In the meantime, I'm planning to make more flexible samples of PLA to put into the dehydrator later this week in a vain effort to see if that might "evaporate" and correct it, but I'm hoping someone would be able to give me a bit of a leg-up on understanding this chemical change and how to account for it. The end result is for the PLA to be grounded and melted into usable forms.

The plastics are visibly similar, which makes it a bit difficult to separate by eye.

Comment: What is PLA  ? Is it Polylactic acid ? And ABS ?

Comment: PLA Polylactic acid
ABS Acrylonitrile butadiene styrene